# Save only time in database using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I use Hibernate and want to save only time in database, so I declare field as a Date and annotate it with temporal type time, but it throws me error regarding format.

**model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "working_policy")
public class OrganizationWorkingPolicy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name= "policy_id")
    private long policyId;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @Column(name= "day")
    private String day;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="hh:mm:ss" )
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private Date startTime;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="HH:mm:ss" )
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private Date endTime;

    // getter and setters
}
```

**Error**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/AppointmentSchedular] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '12:20:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '12:20:00': Can not parse date "12:20:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.appoitment.schedular.model.OrganizationWorkingPolicy["startTime"])] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '12:20:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '12:20:00': Can not parse date "12:20:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.appoitment.schedular.model.OrganizationWorkingPolicy["startTime"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `java.sql.Time;` instead of `import java.util.Date;` in the Hibernate entity class, it should work.