# Persist time with hibernate and java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

(Spring app - MVC)
I defined a table with the column:

```
`time` TIME NOT NULL,
```

In the entity class I have:

```
@Getter @Setter
@NotNull
private java.sql.Time time;
```

In my DTO class, I have:

```
@Getter @Setter
private java.sql.Time time;
```

When I send `"time": "12:10"` from postman I get:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class java.sql.Time] value failed: null (through reference chain: (<points to a field (of java.sql.Time) in my aforementioned DTO class>))`

When I have `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL, java `LocalTime` in both dto and entity, then it works but it persists both time and date. I would like to have time only.

I walked through different previous topics f.e. `Joda-Time-Hibernate` so I used `LocalTime` (in both dto and entity) with annotation `@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalTimeAsTime")` but it didn't work.

Could someone help me, what are the right types (time only) for dto, entity, table's column, so jackson can serialize, hibernate understand and persist.

Comment: Reference might be : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132232/time-in-java-and-hibernate and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560749/save-only-time-in-database-using-hibernate

Comment: You dont have to use any of java.sql.* types.

Comment: Try attribute converter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864625/persist-java-8-localtime-in-jpa

Answer (score 0):

As for serialization, you have to add this to your `application.properties`

`spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false`

this way you will allow simple date form mapping (Java8 requirement)

What I am using to store `LocatDate` as `birthday`

Dependecy:

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.0.12.Final')
```

In entity class

```
@Column
private LocalDate birthday;
```

No additional configuration required. What do I get in the database:

[image]

and the `birthday` is of type `date`

[image]

To have date and time I use `Instant`

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class TimestampedEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(updatable = false)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private Instant createdAt;

    @Column
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private Instant modifiedAt;

    @PrePersist
    private void beforeCreation() {
        this.setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void beforeUpdate() {
        this.setModifiedAt(Instant.now());
    }

}
```

and this persists as `Timestamp` in database.

PS. I am using Spring+JPA+Hibernate+MySQL

Comment: for `@Column private LocalTime time;` (entity) and MySQL `TIME` I am getting: `found [time (Types#TIME)], but expecting [datetime (Types#TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: Yes, try to add that.

Comment: something is wrong. It keeps saying: `found [time (Types#TIME)], but expecting [datetime (Types#TIMESTAMP)]` and my app doesn't event want to run

Comment: OFC it fails on startup during scheme validation obviously. Share your POM or build file

Comment: Is anything I could check by myself ? (I am not sure If I can public that pom file)

Comment: I want only dependencies.